# JSON data in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I am absolut beginner level of web development. I would like to ask how to handle the json data from that link https://www.maxenergy.com.mm/api/max_price_list. I want to show the Diesel price in my page. But how to select the exact key form json data.

```
    [  
   {  
      "Ayeyarwady":[  
         {  
            "price":{  
               "95 Ron Octane":660.00,
               "Premium Diesel":620.00,
               "Diesel":580.00,
               "92 Ron Octane":580.00
            },
            "address":"Aungsan Road, Yay Kyi Township,Ayeyarwady.",
            "station":"Max Energy (Yay Kyi)",
            "longitude":null,
            "latitude":null,
            "telephone":"09977877901, 046-52020"
         },
         {  },
         {  },
         {  },
         {  },
         {  }
       ]
   },
   {  },
   {  },
   {  },
   {  },
   {  }
]
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="aya"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://www.maxenergy.com.mm/api/max_price_list',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          type: 'GET',
        }).done(function(data) {
         $("#aya").html(data.Ayeyarwady.price.Diesel);

        }); 
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That page doesn't seem to support `jsonp`.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(YOUR_RESPONSE);

for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++){                        
JSONObject dataJsonObject = new JSONObject(json.getJSONObject(i));
//FIRST JSONOBJECT
//NOW FROM THIS GET JSONARRAY Ayeyarwady
//AND MAKE IT FRO LOOP AGAIN AND get price and address like...
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: `ReferenceError: JSONArray is not defined`

Comment: try with this.. Json.stringify(url)

Comment: `ReferenceError: Json is not defined`

Comment: is your custom api..?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: this response is comes from your backhand side or so..??

Comment: I don't understand. What does "this response" refer to? You can't have two main verbs in a sentence; "is comes" is an error. What do you mean by "backhand side"? What does "or so" mean? You have two periods and two question marks; is that supposed to be a statement or a question?

Answer (score 0):

the array displayed in your page is part JSON part array (you can tell by the brackets type - `[]` is array, `{}` is JSON.

so you should use `data[0].Ayeyarwady[0].price.Diesel` (data and Ayeyarwady are arrays of objects with one child)

**BUT** this particular API isn't really supporting jsonp, and that's why it isn't working for you, if you add an `error` function callback you'll see that jQuery throws a `parsererror` on the data received.
you'll have to create a proxy server side request to the API, grab the data, parse as JSON and then get that data locally

Comment: Can you please explain with simple code. first i try with dataType : json. I will come error i console, that why I try jsonp.

Comment: since the site is not responding with proper jsonp, you can't get the data using client side code (javascript / jQuery). you'll need to preform a server side request to the site so you could access the data locally. what server side language do you use? (php / .net etc)

Comment: to clarify - since you're getting client-side data from a different server then your own, you can only use `jsonp` - and only if the site you're getting the data from supports it - this one doesn't so you'll have to do a workaround using server-side code

Answer (score -2):

Please change dataType like this,

dataType: 'json',

Comment: Why? What will that achieve?

Comment: datatype = json, jquery will handle response as json and you don't need to parse json

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/: "Cross-domain `"json"` requests are converted to `"jsonp"` unless the request includes `jsonp: false` in its request options."